# snake game - str object is not callable

Tags: python, string

Sorry if the answer is easy, but I'm really stuck on this one...
I'm trying to make a 'Snake game', but I get an error when I try to call the function to make my snake move.
The error states :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Fran\Desktop\SnakeISN.py", line 89, in <module>
    theApp.on_execute()
  File "C:\Users\Fran\Desktop\SnakeISN.py", line 80, in on_execute
    snake.changeDirectionTo(3)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

whenever I start pressing an arrow key...
import pygame
import sys
import random

```
class Snake():
    def __init__(self):
     self.x=400
     self.y=590
     self.direction = "RIGHT"
     self.changeDirectionTo = self.direction

    def changeDirectionTo(self,dir):
     if dir == 1 and not self.direction == 2:
         self.direction = "RIGHT"
     if dir == 2 and not self.direction == 1:
         self.direction = "LEFT"
     if dir == 3 and not self.direction == 4:
         self.direction = "UP"
     if dir == 4 and not self.direction == 3:
         self.direction = "DOWN"

    def move(self, foodPos):
     if self.direction == "RIGHT":
         self.x += 100
     if self.direction == "LEFT":
         self.x -= 100
     if self.direction == "UP":
         self.y -= 100
     if self.direction == "DOWN":
         self.y += 100

class Appli:

    windowX = 800
    windowY = 600

    def __init__(self):
        self._running = True
        self._show_surf = None
        self._image_surf = None
        self.snake = Snake() 

    def on_init(self):
        pygame.init()
        self._show_surf = pygame.display.set_mode((self.windowX,self.windowY), pygame.HWSURFACE)

        pygame.display.set_caption('Snake V2.7')
        self._running = True
        self._image_surf = pygame.image.load("pygame.png").convert()


    def on_event(self, event):
        if event.type == QUIT:
            self._running = False

    def on_loop(self):
        pass

    def on_render(self):
        self._display_surf.fill((0,0,0))
        self._display_surf.blit(self._image_surf,(self.snake.x,self.snake.y))
        pygame.display.flip()

    def on_cleanup(self):
        pygame.quit()

    def on_execute(self):
        snake=Snake()
        if self.on_init() == False:
            self._running = False

        while( self._running ):
            pygame.event.pump()
            action = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if action[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                snake.changeDirectionTo(1)
            if action[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                snake.changeDirectionTo(2)
            if action[pygame.K_UP]:
                snake.changeDirectionTo(3)
            if action[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                snake.changeDirectionTo(4)
            self.on_loop()
            self.on_render()
        self.on_cleanup()


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    theApp = App()
    theApp.on_execute()
```

Anyone knows where the problem is? 
The first time I got this error, I changed all directions "RIGHT" , "LEFT", "UP" , "DOWN" to 1,2,3,4 , hoping that it would solve the 'str call' error, but it didn't...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding the error message is key to solving the issue.

When you call a function, you add parentheses along with any parameters:

```
>>> def func():
...     print('worked!')
...
>>> func()
worked!
```

But what happens when you add parentheses to something that isn't a function?

```
>>> func = 1
>>> func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

>>> func = 'abc'
>>> func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

So your error indicates that the function you tried to call (`changeDirectionTo(3)`) isn't a function, but a string.

Since you have a `def changeDirectionTo` line declaring it as a function, look for other uses of `changeDirectionTo` that override this definition.

The problem is in `def __init__`.  These two lines declare a string and then assign it to the `changeDirectionTo`, overriding the previous function definition.

```
 self.direction = "RIGHT"
 self.changeDirectionTo = self.direction
```

Use a different variable name or remove the line to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks to you I get it now :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! If an answer is useful to you consider upvoting it.  You can also select one answer is the best one by excepting it with a green check on the left

Answer (score 0):

In your snake's `__init__` method you have defined an attribute, `self.changeDirectionTo`, which points to a string and which overrides the method with the same name.

You should delete that line.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this line from your `__init__` method:

```
self.changeDirectionTo = self.direction
```

You've made a function `changeDirectionTo` into a string...

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
 self.changeDirectionTo = self.direction
```

You name a method and instance variable with the same name which hides the method

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hello = 'hello instance variable'

    def hello(self):
        print('hello')

h = Hello()
print(h.hello)  # print out hello instance variable
print(h.hello())  # throw the error you got  TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```